# Enable cross origin iframe use for site page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to enable a site page with embedded power bi report to be displayed in an iframe on a .net app.

I have added  to seattle.master and a custom master file. 
I have also added <%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ClientSidePage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> to the site page aspx file.

I'm still getting this error message 
Refused to display 'https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/Extranet/SitePages/test.aspx' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

what is weird is that if i set that url a level up ie at
https://xxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/Extranet/SitePages/Forms/AllPages.aspx
The iframe has no problem displaying that.
And then i can click on that test link and it will display. Although it will still show me the same error. Images below for clarity. This is the embedded view.
[image]

[image]

[image]